# How to map Response from service when service is returning Map | Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have been working on angular4 for a while, handling JSON response from service. But today I observed my service returning me response like this.

info-response.json

```
{
project: "school management",
class: "X-A"
"student1":{
     "id":"1",
     "name":"Anna"
    },
"student2":{
     "id":"2",
     "name":"Martin"
    }
}
```

how can i model this response and perform operation. as Student1 and Student2 are keys of map and it can extend upto StudentN

Comment: That's not a good practice -- to mix fixed and dynamic fields. If you can change this somehow, then you should do that. Otherwise, you need to iterate over object key/value pairs (e.g. via `Object.entries()`) and check if particular key is a student (maybe it is reliable to check key against regex like `/^student\d+$/`, maybe you should check if value is object with key fields `id` and `name`).

Comment: Which operation do you want to run against that data, exactly? Please provide more information about the problem you're trying to solve.